# Is there a way to connect to the database after the initial connection is made using mysql-connector?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to connect to a MYSQL instance using `mysql.connector` for python. Once the initial connection is established, I want to connect to the database as input by the user.
Here is my implementation:

```py
...

import mysql.connector as sqlcon

connection = sqlcon.connect(
        user=conn_info['user'], password=conn_info['password'], host=conn_info['host'], auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
#conn_info is a dictionary holding the values
cursor = connection.cursor()

db_name = input("Enter db name")
...
```

Is there a way to connect to `db_name` after this step?

Comment: Execute the query `f'USE {db_name}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html):

> To change the current database later, execute a `USE` SQL statement or set the `database` property of the `MySQLConnection` instance.

So you can use:

```
connection.database = db_name
```

to connect to the user-selected database.